# how to save dropdown list selected value to a Xml file?

Tags: asp.net, xml

I have a dropdownlist in my program. I am binding data for dropdownlist from a Xml data source.

```
<asp:XmlDataSource ID="XmlDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="C:\Users\rafat\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\frmPdfUpload\Pdf\Test.xml"></asp:XmlDataSource>



     <asp:DropDownList  
             ID="DropDownList2"  
             runat="server"  
             DataSourceID="XmlDataSource1"  
             DataTextField="Name"  
             OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged"  
             AutoPostBack="true"  
             BackColor="Bisque"  
             >  
        </asp:DropDownList>
```

now i want to save the selected value from the dropdownlist to a new xml file.I am a beginner. I don't know is it possible or not. Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I have Solve This by myself. The code is given below -

```
 protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string file = Server.MapPath("Customers.xml");

        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        XmlNode decNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null);
        doc.AppendChild(decNode);

        XmlNode parentNode = doc.CreateElement("Customers");
        doc.AppendChild(parentNode);

        XmlNode childNode1 = doc.CreateElement("Customer");
        XmlAttribute name = doc.CreateAttribute("name");
        name.Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
        childNode1.Attributes.Append(name);
        parentNode.AppendChild(childNode1);

        doc.Save(file);
        Label1.Text = "XML File Created and data inserted successfully";
    }
```

You just have to create a Xml file name "Customers.xml" into your project folder

Answer (score 0):

I think save a value to a single xml file is not a good choice, save to app.config is better cause it's simple and clean.

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);  
configuration.AppSettings.Settings["Name"].Value = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();  
configuration.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

ref - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx